# How to execute line in previously detached tmux session?

Tags: linux, tmux

I want to execute a line in a previously-detached tmux session for which I must specify the path to the shared socket.

```
$ tmux send-keys -S /var/sharedtmuxsessions/my-01-socket -t my-01 'echo hello' C-m
tmux: unknown option -- S
usage: send-keys [-lR] [-t target-pane] key ...
```

I'm working with version 1.8.

```
$ tmux -V
tmux 1.8
```

This technique (not sure its name) fails too:

```
$ (
  echo hello
) | tmux -S /var/sharedtmuxsessions/my-01-socket attach -t my-01
open terminal failed: not a terminal
```

Answer (score 1):

The order of the parameters is wrong:

```
tmux -S /var/sharedtmuxsessions/my-01-socket send-keys 'echo hello' C-m
```